# Нет появляются кнопки export datatables

Tags: javascript

Datatables
Обрабатываю на стороне клиента, все ок, только кнопки не появляются

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
```

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js  " ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.2.2/js/buttons.print.min.js" ></script>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var json={{ test_data | safe }}

                    $('#test_table').DataTable({
                       data: json.data,   //get the array of object data
                            "columns":[
                                        {"data": "domain"},
                                      ],
                          dom: 'Bfrtip',
                          buttons: [
                            'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
                          ]

                        } );
                        });
```

При обычной проверке на таблице все отображается

```
$('#test_table').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    'copyHtml5', 'excelHtml5', 'pdfHtml5', 'csvHtml5'
  ]
} );
```

Подскажите, может быть я что-то упустил ?

Comment: `var json={{ test_data | safe }}` - что за запись? похоже на какую-то интерполяцию. Покажите что находится внутри этих переменных. Если не показываются кнопки, значит до того как скрипт покажет кнопки в нем происходит ошибка, следовательно покажите ошибку с консоли

Comment: она пустая, пока не обработается функция в джанге и не вернет словарь,
данные в таблице появляются, следовательно он идет по скрипту дальше, только кнопки не видит.

Кнопки должны появится только после того, как вьюшка отработает. Данные есть, кнопок нет)
Консоль пустая, там нет ошибок

Comment: думаю какая-то проблема с ЖЦ. У вас на момент, когда выполняется скрипт, в json уже есть данные? Проверьте, посмотрите что приходит.

Comment: Нет. Выполняется вьюшка и отдает в шаблон словарь, в этот момент выполняется скрипт, где уже есть целый словарь от вьюшки в var json. Данные есть, таблица не слетает, консоль опять же пустая, а кнопочек нет) супер странно